# How much shrimps?

Tags: uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns, countability

if i want to ask about the amount of shrimps that a person eats (kilograms)  per year, should i ask

> How many shrimps do you eat? - > I eat 1 kilo
>   a year.

Or maybe I should ask

> How much shrimps do you eat? - > I eat 1 kilo of shrimps

because the answer supposes uncountable amount, not like " i eat 4 shrimps" but " i eat 2 kilos of shrimps" I hope you got what i mean, thanks.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Individual shrimps are countable, e.g. "there are 50 shrimps in the pool" but, considered as a food, the uncountable noun is usually **shrimp**. So is the plural noun for the food product.

> shrimp noun (ANIMAL) plural shrimps or shrimp a very small sea
>   creature similar to a prawn but smaller, or its flesh eaten as food

[Shrimp](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/shrimp)

You could ask "How much shrimp do you eat in a year?". Of course, in the real world, not many people would be able to give an answer to that question, unless (like for me) the answer is "none".

> Observed annually on May 10, it is National Shrimp Day.  Americans eat
>   more shrimp than any other seafood
>
> One billion pounds of shrimp are eaten every year by Americans*.
>
> The average American consumes 4.0 lbs. of shrimp annually.

[Americans Consume One Billion Pounds Of Shrimp Annually](https://southfloridareporter.com/americans-consume-one-billion-pounds-of-shrimp-annually/)

- I would prefer "One billion pounds of shrimp **is** eaten every year by Americans"

> When a measurement is being described in a sentence, that quantity
>   takes a singular verb form. In such cases, the entire quantity is
>   thought of as a single entity that should be considered together, not
>   separately. See the following examples, in which the entire sample was
>   added or tested at a single time:
>
> In total, 10 g of tissue was tested. (NOT: 10 g of tissue were tested)
>   Five milliliters of solvent was added to the mixture. (NOT: Five
>   milliliters were added)

[Singular and Plural Verbs with Measured Quantities](https://www.aje.com/arc/editing-tip-singular-and-plural-verbs-measured-quantities/)

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to the number of individual shrimp, you use *many*, because they are countable:

> "How many shrimp can you eat?"
>   "I can eat ten of them."

(Note that the plural of [*shrimp*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shrimp) is both *shrimp* ***and*** *shrimps*. Either can be used. It's probably a bit more common to hear the singular form.)

---

If you are referring to shrimp in a general way, you use *much*:

> "How much shrimp can you eat?"
>   "About a pound."

---

Note, however, that these are not absolute rules when it comes to idiomatic speech:

> "How many shrimp would you like?"
>   "I'm having company over, so give me five pounds worth."
>
> "How much shrimp would you like?"
>   "I can probably only manage five of the big ones."

So, while there is a general difference between *much* and *many*, where one is more common in a particular context, both can be used and understood.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want an answer in kilos, so the best way to get that kind of answer is to ask

> How many kilos of shrimp[s] do you eat per year?

The **s** after shrimp is optional, because [shrimp](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/shrimp) is both countable and uncountable, and because the plural of shrimp can be with or without an **s**. [This NGram graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pound%20of%20shrimps%2C%20pound%20of%20shrimp&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpound%20of%20shrimps%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpound%20of%20shrimp%3B%2Cc0) shows that it is a lot more common without an **s**.